# How to fill up a matrix in Python using for loops

Tags: python, steganography

How to add zeroes to the end of a list and fill a matrix with it? 
Currently I have

```
(1,0,1,1,0)
```

How to fill up a matrix such that it looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: I'm not very sure about what you are trying to do. Could you rephrase your goal?

Comment: I believe you mean you want to write a multi-dimensional array that will mimic the notion of a matrix.  Most languages do not have a specific matrix datatype,  instead you make an array of arrays, such that [0][0] is the first value of the first sub array and [1][0] is the first value of the next array.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to pad a list at the end with zeros, but your example shows the padding at the beginning (if you flatten it row by row at least). And how would you reshape a longer list? 3xn, mx3, mxn? Your title says that you want to do it with loops, but you don't say why that is a constraint. And how is the steganography tag relevant to the question as stated? I can see it being relevant to padding a bitstream to be a multiple of a number, but you haven't made this "relevance" relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you have clearly added the zeroes to the beginning of the matrix rather than the end but whatever.

To extend a list to one with 9 items with preceeding zeroes:

```
list_out = [0]*(9-len(list_in)) + list_in
```

to extend a list to one with 9 items with trailing zeroes just reverse the order:

```
list_out = list_in + [0]*(9-len(list_in))
```

We can convert a list with 9 items to a matrix using

```
matrix = [li[0:3,li[3:6],li[6:9]
```

so eg.

```
list_in = [1,2,3]
li = list_in + [0]*(9-len(list_in))
matrix = [li[0:3],li[3:6],li[6:9]]
```

gives

> [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]